# Tkinter: cannot change Label using variable, variable results as “not defined”

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I have a fundamental understanding of Python, and I have managed to make a basic number guessing game. Whenever the user inputs their guess, I want it to print out, in my GUI, if the answer was right or wrong. Rather than having the machine add a new label every time the user guessed, I want a single label, that is updated through a variable, set in my function.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Guessing Game")
window.geometry("600x200")

def numCallback():
    global guess, secretnumber, result
    if int(guess.get()) == secretnumber:
        **result = StringVar()
        result.set('Congratulations! You guessed the number.')**
    if int(guess.get()) > secretnumber:
        **result = StringVar()
        result.set('Too high, try guessing again.')**
    if int(guess.get()) < secretnumber:
        **result = StringVar()
        result.set('Too low, try guessing again.')**

instruction = Label(window, text="Input a guess between 1 to 100.")
instruction.pack()
guess = Entry(window)
guess.pack()
confirmer = Button(window, text="Confirm Guess", command=numCallback)
confirmer.pack()
instruction = Label(window, text="Input a guess between 1 to 100.")
instruction.pack()
***result.trace(window, textvariable=result)***

secretnumber = randint(1, 100)

window.mainloop()
```

I have marked what may be external causes for the issue with 2 asterisks, and have marked the traceback source with 3 asterisks. When I run the program, I get a runtime error telling me that the variable “result” is not defined. I have made the variable global, and have checked the case sensitivity, so I am unsure as to why it is not functioning correctly.

Comment: Where's global variable `result` defined? Also note that marking your code up with the asterisks that way doesn't make them display any different and makes your code un-runable—I suggest you add comments via `#` to mark lines instead.

Comment: Ooh, don’t worry about the asterisks. I added it to the code block just for this, they aren’t in my real code. Result is defined globally in my numCallback function. First indented line.

Comment: Declaring it `global` in the `numCallback` function doesn't define it. Outside all functions before caling `mainloop()` add a `result = StringVar()`.

Comment: Ooohh. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so I’m getting a new error. It’s telling me it got an unexpected keyword argument ‘textvariable’.

Comment: Move the `result = StringVar()` up before any references are made to it — sorry I should have mentioned that in my previous suggestion.

Comment: Disregard, solved problem.